# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: SharedPreference error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I'm new to android. I use Shared Preferences named "MyPref" to store and retrieve values. The code logic is, "MyPref" stores userid, usertype (customer, driver). In my `SplashActivity` I have written the following code. If user id is not null and user type equals either customer or driver the activity should navigate accordingly. But I get the following error: Kindly help

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
```

SplashActivity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        pref = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        editor = pref.edit();
        String userid=pref.getString("userid","");
        Log.e("userid",userid);
        if(userid!=null)
        {
            String usertype=pref.getString("usertype1","");
            if(usertype.equals("customer"))
            {
                Intent customer=new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeFragment.class);
                startActivity(customer);
            }
            else
            {
                Intent driver=new Intent(SplashActivity.this, DriverDashboardFragment.class);
                startActivity(driver);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Intent walk=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,WalkThroughActivity.class);
            startActivity(walk);
        }

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove context from this statement:

```
pref = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
```

it should be `pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);`

You are facing this issue because context is not initialized.
You don't need context reference here because `AppCompatActivity` is child of Context class. So you can directly call `getSharedPreferences`.

After this your app is crashing because you are try to start a fragment via startActivity method. To start a fragment inside an activity:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.container,new DriverDashboardFragment(),"driverDashboard");
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

replace above code with:

```
Intent driver=new Intent(SplashActivity.this, DriverDashboardFragment.class);
                startActivity(driver);
```

You need to add this in your xml of this activity:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: I did it and now I get this error

Comment: Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {DriverDashboardFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?. There is no need go initialising Fragment class in Manifest file right?

Comment: can you post complete log with question?

Comment: if DriverDashboardFragment is a fragment then you can't start a fragment via startActivity method

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. Where should I include this code?

Comment: Thank u it worked

Comment: You're Welcome @Elackya

Answer (score 1):

Your context is null

just add this line after setcontentView

```
 context= this;
```

it will not crash..